# Domain-Driven Design with different roles

Tags: typescript, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am new to DDD. I want to build an application implementing DDD, but I have a problem with the Roles.

The application has many roles like `customer`, `admin`, etc. The `admin` can create, edit, and delete `post`. The `customer` can only comment on the `post`.

Base on that description, I think the `post` should have different methods in those 2 different contexts. Should I create 2 directories for those 2 roles and duplicate the `post` in each directory?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Be careful not to confuse how you physically structure code with how you logically conceive things (DDD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different domains and there are different bounded contexts.

Your core domain that effects business state changes is only concerned with how to implement those mutations.  It is not terribly concerned about security or access control.

Your application/integration layer is the gatekeeper and decides who gets to call what on the domain.  For that you may even use another *Identity and Access Management* (IAM) bounded context which manages the authorisation.

As an example I like to use a physical calculator to represent my domain.  I can access absolutely any and all functions on the calculator.  Something outside of the calculator would need to determine which buttons I can press.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think you have the basis for a good answer, but you might need to elaborate so that the OP knows how to apply it in his situation.  E.g. how does bounded context help him.

Comment: Do you mean the domain does not have to know anything about data access control or role-based system and the application layer will handle that? So I should not divide the bounded context into `manage post` and `explore post` but simply `post`? Please let me know if I get it wrong.

Comment: @Ngọc Nguyễn, Since the domain would focus on state mutations you typically shouldn't use your domain to query data.  Requests go in and out comes changes.  I tend to implement the querying as close as possible to the database that stores the relevant (read models).  I mention this in terms of the `explore post`.  Your domain would not implement data storage either but would define repository interfaces that the relevant infrastructure components implement.  Querying and role-based access control (RBAC) are application/integration layer concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you would need to distinguish between posts in different roles.  Off the top of my head, it seems potentially practical to:

- include the role as an argument with the operations on posts, so that a post can reject an attempt by a customer to edit/delete a post.
- route the operation through the user, which validates that its role allows the operation.

Those can be elaborated on and could be combined.

Comment: So the `post` domain can be used for both management context and `customer` (read post) context. The permission to perform actions is handled by the `controller`. Am I understand correctly?

Comment: Including "a role" would be problematic for users with multiple roles, it's better to include all permissions. But it's even better to not to include anything and just have another security layer that decides what is allowed and what disallowed.

Comment: @WiktorZychla So I should allow or not allow the action to be performed in the controller layer, not in the domain layer?

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn: yes, in my opinion. You could have a separate identity & access control bounded context that deals with authorization but still, orchestration of the two, the authorization and managing `posts`, is done at the controller level.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Could you tell me what are your bounded contexts to solve the problem that I have mentioned above? I mean to both manage and explore the `post` in the domain. Would you call it `post` or `post managing` or something?

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn: this one that related to posts is either just `posts`, I can only guess but I believe you have both post management and commenting in one context. The other one is the [identity context](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367659/implementing-ddd-users-and-permissions).